# How to add properly jQuery library to the Spring MVC project?

Tags: jquery, spring, spring-mvc

I would like to ask you how can I add properly jQuery library to the Spring MVC project. In `src/webapp` directory I have `resources` folder. I have created inside `js` directory. And then I have pasted downloaded jQuery library. But Eclipse have found a few errors and now I can't run my project. So what is the way to add and use properly jQuery library in Spring MVC project? Maybe using Maven add some dependencies in `POM.xml`?

I have founded this question [How to include the jQuery library in a Spring-MVC Eclipse project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4137128/how-to-include-the-jquery-library-in-a-spring-mvc-eclipse-project) but it haven't resolved my problem.

Comment: search for how to serve static content with spring. (mvc:resources, a different servlet, a content delivery server) You can't just throw a js in src/main/resources and think it will be included on the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Just put that in the head of your jsp page. From [here](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide). Or if you want to manually supply your own jquery file add this to app context (and create javascript directory in yr webapp folder obviously):

```
<mvc:resources location="/javascript/" mapping="/javascript/**" />
```

then in jsp

```
<c:url var="jq" value="/javascript/jquery.js" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="${jq}"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But when I want to supply my own jquery file still it causes errors in 'webapp/resources/js' directory.

Comment: change the resources defintiion in appcotnacxt to match your folder set up, don't copy mine ad verbatim

Comment: I have of course adjusted your code to my project. However I have to look closer.

Answer (score 1):

Use the google cdn :

```
<script type="text/javascript src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
```